# ContentBlockerRequestHandler class not invoked?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have added content block extension to my project.
& I enabled extension from safari setting, but beginrequest method  not getting called. Any idea will be highly appreciated.

```
class ContentBlockerRequestHandler: NSObject, NSExtensionRequestHandling {

    func beginRequest(with context: NSExtensionContext) {
        let attachment = NSItemProvider(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "blockerList", withExtension: "json"))!

        let item = NSExtensionItem()
        item.attachments = [attachment]

        context.completeRequest(returningItems: [item], completionHandler: nil)
    }
   // All I need is to get called beginRequest method
```

but I am getting error

> Failed to look up content blocker 'com.xx.xx.xx'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable App group from `xcode` capabilities 
& test app with Action, trigger with help of `safari browser`. 
[image]